# Migrating from clearcase to mercurial

Tags: version-control, mercurial, clearcase

What tools are available to migrate from clearcase to mercurial? Is it possible to move history? What kind of limitations are there?

Answer (score 12):

Do not forget that ClearCase (**Central** VCS) and Mercurial (**Distributed** VCS) are very different.
See [Core ClearCase concepts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645008/what-are-the-basic-clearcase-concepts-every-developer-should-know/645771#645771) for a full list.

In the case of a migration, that means you are dealing with a *repository-centric* VCS (Mercurial) which implies "working with timelines" (a timeline being a commit, building a new changeset)
In ClearCase though, there is no global timeline, as each *file* is committed individually (file-centric VCS).

So for a migration, you need to setup a ClearCase dynamic view with a config spec you will change to list all relevant "ClearCase timelines" (labels for non-UCM views or even better: baselines for UCM views) and import that fixed state into Mercurial.
And repeat the process until the most recent label/baseline.

The idea is: there is often no need to import the *all* history of *all* the files when migrating from ClearCase to another (D)VCS. Only the "significant" changes need to be recorded.
I would not recommend the "[Conversion of ClearCase repo to Mercurial](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/wiki/ClearCaseConversion)" article, especially for large and old ClearCase repositories.

See also [SVN migration for other considerations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542479/what-is-the-best-strategy-when-migrating-from-clearcase-to-svn).

Comment: Why not the recommandation of "Conversion of ClearCase repo to Mercurial" ? Because it will take up too much space and time to make it ?
I kinda need that full import. At least to have it under a free of charge repository system like git. Then, when archived, maybe we could just begin with a new git repo with the full history not available and just there for reference purpose ?

Comment: @Dolanor ClearCase exports poorly to a revision-based system because it is file-centric: meaning each version are created independently for each file (as opposed a single revision on a commit for the *full* repo). Hence, it is harder to extract successive state of the ClearCase repo to export into a revision-based VCS (SVN, Hg, Git, ...). I usually keep the ClearCase repo in read-only mode for archive, and import only the last few tags or baselines. Much quicker that way.

Comment: That's true, but keeping an archive of clearcase makes you need a ClearCase license if you want to view it. Having it under a free source control means archive for free. But more work to do it. I already tried the [git-cc tools](https://github.com/charleso/git-cc) but have problems with it. I'll try to fix it or create another tool for my needs

Comment: @Dolanor good point. I look forward seeing your tool on GitHub ;)

Comment: Don't you worry I will, or patch git-cc. Just need to understand the crazy functionning of clearcase to do it. The git-cc did a lshistory that did a backward history listing given my configspec. Thus, stuff which should have been on main branch were displayed on /JUNK_TO_DELETE/ since day 1. I guess my configspec need to be updated each time I check the history. It will be long and painful I guess ^^'

Answer (score 4):

You might start on the mercurial site at [Information for Clearcase/UCM Users](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/wiki/ClearcaseInfo) and at [Conversion of ClearCase repositories to Mercurial](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/wiki/ClearCaseConversion)