# Can you share your customized scripts for converting from cc to svn please?

Tags: svn, migration, clearcase

I have to convert a large cc code base - 15 vobs all symbolically linked on windows to a svn repository on solaris.  Any help, step by step instructions, scripts are welcome.  Thanks

Comment: You might consider rephrasing your question as a question. This is more of a question and answer site than a resource sharing site. Do you have a script started? Perhaps someone could help get that working for you.

Comment: Read also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239646/migrating-away-from-clearcase : what do you actually need to export from those 15 vobs? The *all* history?

Answer (score 2):

Clearvision makes a [nice product](http://www.clearvision-cm.com/products/clearcase-and-subversion-complete-integration.html) for this. We are considering this for my current company.

There's [this product](http://www.polarion.com/products/svn/svn_importer_features.php) from Polarion, too.