# How to manage ACL for Git repos?

Tags: git, gerrit, gitolite, bitbucket-server

I decided to migrate from ClearCase to git. But plain Git is not useful in many ways.

The plan is to have gitolite/stash/gerrit as admin tool. is there any comparison available?
We are looking for ACL, branch control and basic cm process from the above tools.

Note: code review is of less importance.

How to get a fine-grained ACL on Git repositories?

Comment: Gerrit has a pretty extensive ACL system to gate access and well as enforce some process aspects; see https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.8/access-control.html. I believe Gitolite provides at least some of these features. While it might be clear to you exactly what you're looking for when you say "branch control and basic cm process", you'll probably get better answers if you are more specific.

Answer (score 4):

The difference between ClearCase and Git is [illustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/645771/6309).
And since Git is distributed, it doesn't provide fine-grained ACL.
There is no authentication or authorization: this is part of the challenges posed by a DVCS.
(See "[Distributed Version Control Systems and the Enterprise - a Good mix?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5685757/6309)")

The only way to add that is to install an **[authorization layer](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/auth.html)** behind an authentication service, on a server dedicated to managed "blessed" Git repos.

The tool you need is gitolite: see "[How Gitolite works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13320256/6309)".

Don't neglect the [migration process from ClearCase to Git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/861554/6309): the repos in Git are much smaller than a huge ClearCase Vob.

Comment: @nowox Congrats! Git itself does not hold ACSs, but repos hosting servers do (GitHub Enterprise, GitLab, ...)