# Migrating from Clearcase LT (UCM) to Subversion

Tags: svn, clearcase

I am sure this question has been asked hundreds of time and been responded equally. I am trying to get a clear picture of my effort before I embark on this. I want to know if SVNImporter or any other tool out there helps me migrate my UCM VOBs to Subversion repos. I dont mind losing some history. Also please share your strategies if there are no tools out there. I was told by someone that I would have to rebase my view with each baseline from oldest to the newest and incrementally commit that code into Subversion. While this seems to be plain and simple but considering the number of VOBs we have here, this would be a gigantic task for us to do manually. Is there any script out there that I can use to automate this process. Comments please!!!

Thanks
Gnan

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57494/recommendation-on-tools-to-migrate-from-clearcase-to-svn

Answer (score 0):

There is no SVN importer for UCM components that I know of.

The idea is indeed to rebase the relevant baselines on a export stream (read-only stream made only to read/access the baseline X of a component) and commit that in a subversion view made at the same place than the ClearCase UCM view.
A really advanced script would be able to create SVN branches for each streams where a baseline has been put.

After that, that depends on:

- the number of components (do you have one per vob, or several within a vob),
- the number of baselines you want to import
- the number of streams you have to take into account if you want to create the corresponding SVN branches.

You also need to decide of the number of SVN repos you want to create for those components. Technically one can be enough, but it can be wise to group those components in logical groups within a SVN repo.