# Polarion SVN Importer Sources

Tags: svn, migration, clearcase

There is an Apache 2 licensed tool called Polarion SVN Importer. Has anybody the sources for this and would put them on Github? I guess Apache License gives the right to do this.

The tool can be downloaded at [polarion.plm.automation.siemens.com](https://polarion.plm.automation.siemens.com/products/svn/svn_importer) but there are no sources available.

Looks like even if a software is open source, its sources can get lost.

See [Recommendation on Tools to migrate from Clearcase to SVN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57494/recommendation-on-tools-to-migrate-from-clearcase-to-svn)

Comment: Not that I know of. And I still recommend my approach: http://stackoverflow.com/a/662899/6309

Comment: I guess the Polarion tool calls cleartool, so custom scripts would do that too. I have no idea how much work scripts would be, yours aren't on github by chance?

Comment: No it is just a matter of listing all the labels (or UCM baselines) we want to export, checkout them in a dynamic view (by changing its config spec: cleartool setcs) and import them in another SCM (in 2017, that would be Git)

Comment: I have just found https://github.com/charleso and https://therub.org/2013/07/19/clearcase-to-git/ and will have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

As the [OP weberjn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/503025/weberjn) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42924199/polarion-svn-importer-sources#comment72953183_42924199), there are a couple of scripts for Exporting ClearCase to a VCS, but generally it is for the DVCS Git, which works by commits, and not by file version like ClearCase.
(See "[What are the basic ClearCase concepts every developer should know?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/645771/6309)")

But the idea remains the [one I described before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/662899/6309): for each ClearCase label or UCM baseline, you checkout them and import in your Git working tree.

One easy way is to do:

- `cleartool setcs` (a config spec with your label) or `cleartool rebase <yourBaseline>`,
- `cd /path/to/my/git/repo`
- `git --work-tree=/path/to/clearcase/view  add .`

That last command will automatically detect the files added/modified or removed in your Git repo compared to the previous import.